# python distutils does not include data_files

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I am new to distutils.. I am trying to include few data files along with the package.. here is my code..

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Scrapper',
      version='1.0',
      description='Scrapper',      
      packages=['app', 'db', 'model', 'util'],
      data_files=[('app', ['app/scrapper.db'])]      
     )
```

The zip file created after executing `python setup.py sdist` does not include the scrapper.db file. I have scrapper.db file in the app directory..

thanks for the help.

Comment: A remark unrelated to your question: I’d recommend you to use one top-level package name, for example scrapper, instead of using four very widely used names for four packages.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You probably need to add a `MANIFEST.in` file containing `"include app/scrapper.db"`.

It's a bug in distutils that makes this necessary: anything in `data_files` or `package_data` should be included in the generated `MANIFEST` automatically. But in Python 2.6 and earlier, it is not, so you have to include it in `MANIFEST.in`.

The bug is fixed in Python 2.7.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same problem with Python 2.7.1+. I found [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue2279) but I don't understand why the status is `committed/rejected`. Any guidance on how to solve without falling back to using MANIFEST.in? Thanks!

Comment: The status committed/rejected is used with fixed bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing MANIFEST, that way distutils will be forced to regenerate it.

Note: I've been using python 3.x, so I don't know if this works with 2.x or not.

Comment: You misunderstood my answer. I do not recommend creating a MANIFEST file. I am talking about "MANIFEST.in", the manifest template file. This allows you to _add_ to what's included in the automatically-generated MANIFEST. Because of a bug in distutils in all Python versions up to and including 2.6, data_files and package_data entries are not included in the automatically-generated MANIFEST unless you add them to a MANIFEST.in file.

Comment: @Carl Meyer I wasn't commenting on what you did or didn't say. I only wanted to reference an answer that went into more detail on that part (which wasn't my main point.) And I used MANIFEST generally; I probably should have written MANIFEST.in (I've since changed it.) Sorry if I misrepresented your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edited answer is now simply incorrect :/ distutils generates a MANIFEST for you whether or not you provide MANIFEST.in. MANIFEST.in allows you to add to the contents of the generated MANIFEST file.

Comment: @Carl Meyer Alright. I went ahead and removed all the junk that wasn't relevant to what I was trying to convey. Hopefully I didn't mess something else up. Thanks.