# Where are 'package data' files?

Tags: python, virtualenv, packaging, pip, distutils

I've created package with distutils including package data.
When i look in tar.gz of my package I see expected files, BUT after package installation (by pip or by 'python setup.py install') there is no any package data. Only python scripts included. My `setup.py` is:

```
# py3.3
#from packaging.core import setup
# py3.2
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name = 'mypkg',
    version = '0.7dev',
    author = 'Projekt Alef',
    author_email = 'tymoteusz.jankowski@gmail.com',
    packages = [
        'my_pkg',
        'my_pkg/tests',
        'my_pkg/plugins',
    ],
    #scritps=['bin/setup.sh',],
)
```

Comment: Can you include your `setup.py`?

Comment: sure, it's here [setup.py](http://pastebin.com/a9Bap8vP)

Comment: packages must be a list of dotted names: should be mypkg.tests, not mypkg/tests.

Comment: Related: [python distutils does not include data_files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2994396/95735)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package data to be installed should be included as a `package_data={}` dictionary passed to the `setup()` function. Each dictionary gives the module (package) to be installed and a list of patterns to find data files to be installed from/with it, such as:

```
package_data = {
    'exceptional_middleware': [ 'templates/http_responses/*.html' ],
}
```

Additionally, you may prefer not to install your tests (just drop `pkg/tests` from the `packages` list).

Comment: What about MANIFEST.in?
I thought the MANIFEST.in is enough. All the more desired 'package data' files are included in my 'python setup.py sdist' output.
The problem is that the package (with all files i want) after installation lost 'package data' files. O_o

Comment: Having something in the sdist means it'll be distributed to anyone who wants to install it, *not* that it'll get installed. I can't remember offhand the details of MANIFEST.in vs package_data, and the python doc site is down right now. Looking at an example I have here, it's in both, which seems ridiculous but apparently works.

Comment: You're 100% right. Manifest.in is NOT enough.. . Placing package_data var in setup function is mandatory to achieve that. O_o
Thanks :)

Comment: It depends on your Python version.  In 2.7, distutils was fixed so that files included in package_data don’t need to be added to MANIFEST.in.