# Install Bash completion together with distutils / pip 

Tags: python, pip, distutils, setup.py, bash-completion

I have created a simple Python module and want to distribute it with pip. I also want to install a Bash completion file together with the module.
I'm installing the module with Python 2.7.1+ and pip 0.8.2.

I have this setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='jenkinsmon',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Jenkins Job Monitor',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    scripts=['bin/jenkinsmon'],
    data_files=[
        ('/etc/bash_completion.d', ['extras/jenkinsmon.completion']),
    ],
    install_requires = [
        'autojenkins',
        'argparse'
    ],
)
```

Now if I try to install the package with `pip install -e .`, the Bash completion file never gets installed together with the package.
I also tried workarounds by specifying a MANIFEST.in, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994396/python-distutils-does-not-include-data-files):

MANIFEST.in:

```
include extras/jenkinsmon.completion
```

But this also doesn't help - the completion files won't get installed.
What can I do to install the Bash completion files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error (besides not reading the pip-documentation in general) was just to add `-e` to the `pip install` parameters, which means to install in  "editable" mode. To quote the [documentation](http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html)

> Using the --editable or -e option, pip has the capability to install
>   directly from a version control repository (it currently supports
>   Subversion, Mercurial, Git, and Bazaar):
>
> `pip install -e
>   svn+http://svn.colorstudy.com/INITools/trunk#egg=initools-dev`
>
> This
>   option shells out to the commandline client for each respective VCS,
>   so you must have the VCS installed on your system. The repo URL must
>   begin with svn+ (or hg+, git+, or bzr+) and end with #egg=packagename;
>   otherwise, pip supports the same URL formats and wire protocols
>   supported by the VCS itself.
>
> Pip will checkout the source repo into a src/ directory inside the
>   virtualenv (i.e. pip_test_env/src/initools-dev), and then run python
>   setup.py develop in that source repo. This “links” the code directly
>   from the repo into the virtualenv’s site-packages directory (by adding
>   the repo directory into easy-install.pth), so changes you make in the
>   source checkout are effective immediately.
>
> If you already have a local VCS checkout you want to keep using, you
>   can just use pip install -e path/to/repo to install it “editable” in
>   the same way.

So to install the package permanently into the System, I have to remove -r, then the Bash-completion files are installed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

MANIFEST.in only describes additional files to be included in source distributions; it has nothing to do with installing.

Does the file get installed if you run `python setup.py install`?  pip relies on setuptools, so maybe it inherits its behavior of installing everything in only one “egg” directory/zipfile.

Comment: the file gets actually installed when running `python setup.py install`.  But I want to install it with pip, since only then it can be installed from a remote Git repository. I'll ask on the virtualenv group  http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv?hl=en