# Including resources in a Python package using setup.py

Tags: python, web

I'm working on a website project.

When I use setup.py and run setup.py build, the build script excludes all of the resources in my web site (basically all of the non python files).  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most reliable way I've found to include extra files in a distribution using [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) is to provide a [MANIFEST.in](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest) file. Place this file in the same directory as your `setup.py` and include in it the list of resource files you require. For example, your `MANIFEST.in` file might like this:

```
include resources/somefile.txt resources/*.png 
recursive-include resources/static *.png *.jpg *.css *.js
```

See the [distutils documentation](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) for more details.

Though I prefer the [MANIFEST.in](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest) method, if you are using [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools) or distribute, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py) for an alternative method of doing the same thing.