# Python - Trouble in building executable

Tags: python, selenium, wxpython

I'm a python programmer and I'm trying to build an executable binary to distribute my software to my clients, even if it's not fully executable I want to be able to distribute my software in a way so that it is convenient for the end user.

I have already tried PyInstaller as well as Py2Exe and I'm facing the same problem with a particular software.

I used the splinter module for my program (which of course is a new high level framework to interact with other frameworks like Selenium) and every time I try to compile it there seems to be a file called "webdriver.xpi" that is always left out from the final package and therefore when the program attempts to execute the web-driver it fails with an IO Error saying that the file "webdriver.xpi" was not found....but other than that the GUI and everything works perfectly fine.

So is there a way to include it even manually? I tried including it manually by browsing to the specific folder @ library.zip file but it didn't work.

I'm not really expert in this matter and I rely on GUI2Exe for building everything...and I would really appreciate some advice if possible on how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the setup.py script you used for py2exe?

Comment: Cannot you just add the file to the application directory before running it?

Answer (score 10):

I was at this all day and found a workaround, it's sneaky but it works. In the error message I was receiving I noticed that there was a space between in library .zip. I could not trace it down in the source code for py2exe or selenium. I too had tried putting the xpi file in the library zip and it did not work. The workaround is:

1. In your setup file use these options:

   ```
   setup(
       console=['yourFile.py'],
       options={
               "py2exe":{
                       "skip_archive": True,
                       "unbuffered": True,
                       "optimize": 2
               }
       }
   )
   ```
2. Run the py2exe install
3. Copy the xpi file into the dist directory

That should do it.

Comment: I agree with aknatn, I've found the solution to this problem long time ago but totally forgot that I posted the question here. The main solution is whatever you do even with a gui builder like GUI2Exe, just make sure the final package is not zipped or anything and everything is unpacked in a folder to which you can add .xpi file manually and make it work. Later I used something like NSIS to package it into a cool installation wizard with license agreements, key files, etc. to distribute it to third parties. I must say I've learned a lot from messing around, trying to get Python to work :)

Comment: Lol I did try that...it says Vote Up requires 15 reputation xD

Comment: Rather than manually copying them, why not use the `py2exe` setup option `datafiles=[('path/copy/them/to', ['list/of/file/paths/this.txt'])]`?

Answer (score 1):

You need an instruction in your `setup.py` to include any resource files in your distribution. There is a couple of ways of doing this (see distutils, setuptools, distribute - depending on what you are using to build your distribution), but the [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) wiki has an [example](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/AddingConfigFiles).

You may need to use [this py2exe tip](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI) to find your resources if you're installing them into the same directory as your exe.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700270/including-resources-in-a-python-package-using-setup-py/7700659#7700659) for some additional info on including resource files in your distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution of your question:
I have modify a code little and it should be work since I had a same issue and I solved it:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

wd_base = 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\site-packages\\selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg    \\selenium\\webdriver'
RequiredDataFailes = [
('selenium/webdriver/firefox', ['%s\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi'%(wd_base), '%s\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'%(wd_base)])
]

setup(
windows=[{"script":"gui_final.py"}],options={"py2exe":{"skip_archive": True,"includes":["sip"]}},
data_files=RequiredDataFailes,

)
```

Comment: when I tried your script it spits out an error regarding sip. being not defined or unknown

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I wanted to give an updated answer to avoid suggesting that programmers do something manually.

There is a `py2exe` option to specify a list of data files as tuples.  `(pathtocopyto, [list of files and where to get them])`

Example:

```
from disutils.core import setup
import py2exe

wd_base = 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver'
RequiredDataFailes = [
    ('selenium/webdriver/firefox', ['%s\\firefox\\webdriver.xpi'%(wd_base), '%s\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'%(wd_base)])
]

setup(
    console=['MyScript.py'],
    data_files=RequiredDataFiles,
    options={
        **mypy2exeopts
    }
)
```

The only downside I am aware of currently is that you still need `skip_archive = True`.  There are workarounds to get the data files in the library.zip, but I haven't had much luck with the webdriver's info.