# packing selenium with py2exe

Tags: python, selenium, py2exe

I'm trying to pack selenium with py2exe howerever despite following the instructions here [Python - Trouble in building executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701855/python-trouble-in-building-executable)

with the setup.py being:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['PlanOfCareModified9GUI.pyw'],
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                    "skip_archive": True,
                    "unbuffered": True,
                    "optimize": 2
            }
    }
)
```

copying and pasting the `webdriver_prefs.json`and `webdriver.xpi` into the dist directory as instructed by the link above. it still spits out this:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Python34\\dist\\lib
rary.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdriver_prefs.json'
```

I have been searching all over the internet for about 2 days now and still found nothing. The closest I came to a solution was on the link above. but none of the answers fixes this issue.

I am on Python 3.4
and am using selenium 2.45.0

I've even tried putting the `webdriver_prefs.json`and `webdriver.xpi` inside library.zip but when the app is ran the error is still there.

how do we solve this

Comment: Have you tried the `data_files` option within `py2exe`? http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files

Comment: @TimMcNamara actually I did. All the answers on the link I gave I tried. and one of them used data_files. still has the same error