# Py2Exe - Firefox raises exception

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, py2exe, setup.py

I'm trying to create an `exe` file using `Py2Exe`. For debugging purposes, there is an option to use `Firefox webdriver` instead of `PhantomJS` which is headless and one `phantomjs.exe` file inside the main directory is enough.

Ok so everything fine, but when I create an exe file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["main.py"])
```

The program raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 218, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 113, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 48, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.pyc", line 65, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Milano\\PycharmProject
s\\Velvet\\WebDbUploader\\dist\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdr
iver_prefs.json'
```

Do you have any idea what to do?

IMPORTANT EDIT:

So I've found inside `site-packages`...`selenium`..`firefox` the `webdriver_prefs.json` and copied it into the `..WebDbUploader\dist\library.zip\selenium\webdriver\firefox` and no change... still the same error occures.

Comment: any news on this question?

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy `webdriver_prefs.json` and `webdriver.xpi` and from `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox` to `dist\selenium\webdriver\firefox`. It should be enough.

For more details you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701855/python-trouble-in-building-executable).