# Py2exe - import issues

Tags: python, selenium, import, py2exe

I'm trying to create an executable file using `Py2Exe`. If I use `PhantomJS Selenium webdriver` instead of `Firefox`, everything works fine. The problem is when I try to use `Firefox webdriver`.

It raises this exception (when executing exe file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 218, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 113, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.pyc", line 48, in __init__
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.pyc", line 65, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Milano\\PycharmProject
s\\Velvet\\WebDbUploader\\dist\\library.zip\\selenium\\webdriver\\firefox\\webdr
iver_prefs.json'
```

So I've found inside `site-packages...selenium..firefox` the `webdriver_prefs.json` and copied it into the `..WebDbUploader\dist\library.zip\selenium\webdriver\firefox` and no change... still the same error occures.

Now, I've solved this. I just unzip `library.zip`, copy those files inside it and zip it again. But now, there is a new error which says that it can't import `os` module which is weird since there is no problem with this import when I use `PhantomJS`.

Is there some way to repair this? Maybe use just not zipped library or something like that?

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to copy `webdriver_prefs.json` and `webdriver.xpi` and from `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox` to `dist\selenium\webdriver\firefox`. It should be enough.

For more details you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701855/python-trouble-in-building-executable).