# spell check with python and enchant

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyenchant

I want to have a spell check feature in my `PyQt4` project and it seems [pyenchant](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/) is a good choice to do this thing. It's work prefect. but I want to make my own dictionary of words and feed the module with them. Is it possible at all?

after that, how can I make an easy process to use this new dictionary on other computers that want to use my original program? I don't want to make user install some strange program and dictionaries to use my simple program.

PS: I'm on a Linux system.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Personal Word List](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#personal-word-lists) feature. Add words via `pwl` object:

```
>>> pwl = enchant.request_pwl_dict("mywords.txt")
```

Use word list:

```
>>> d2 = enchant.DictWithPWL("en_US", "mywords.txt")
>>> d2.check("Hello")
True
```

To install "mywords.txt" use `package_data`. See [Including non-Python files with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1612733/4279)

Comment: Yeah, I used it before, but after running my program, all words in the file vanished! I thought maybe I used wrong function.