# Export Python to exe with "py2exe", Selenium error

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling, exe, py2exe

i am trying to export Python app With GUI & Selenium, using "py2exe"

setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

data_files = [('selenium\\webdriver\\firefox', ['C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\\firefox\webdriver.xpi']),
              ('selenium\\webdriver\\firefox', ['C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium-2.44.0-py3.4.egg\selenium\webdriver\\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json'])]

setup(
    name='app',
    version='1.0',
    console = {'Main.py'}, requires=['easygui', 'selenium'], 
    data_files=data_files,

)
```

i get a error -
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Python34\dist\lib
rary.zip\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver_prefs.json'

i try to add the files manually to the zip, did not work.
any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure [`MANIFEST.in` file](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#the-manifest-in-template):

> A MANIFEST.in file can be added in a project to define the list of
>   files to include in the distribution built by the sdist command.

For example, you can include all `.json` files to the build:

```
recursive-include *.json
```

Also see:

- [Including non-Python files with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)
- [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)

Comment: i having some trouble understanding this, i have a manifest.py, so where i can enter the command "recursive-include *.json"
 ?

Comment: @user2920421 MANIFEST.in file has a special meaning, please study the docs and the mentioned in the answer links, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I met and have solved the similar problem:

1. Copy webdriver.xpi and webdriver_prefs.json into your exe directoy.
2. Modify C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py:

Change "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**)" into -> "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), '..\..\..\..\'", has two places.