# setuptools: adding additional files outside package

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a `python` application that has a fixed layout which I cannot change. I would like to wrap it up using setuptools, e.g. write a `setup.py` script.

Using the official documentation, I was able to write a first template. However, the application in question uses a lot of additional data files that are not explicitly part of any package. Here's an example source tree:

```
somepackage
   __init__.py
   something.py
   data.txt
additionalstuff
   moredata.txt
INFO.txt
```

Here's the trouble: The code in `something.py`  reads the files `moredata.txt` and `INFO.txt`. For the former, I can monkeypatch the problem by adding an empty `additionalstuff/__init__.py` file to promote `additionalstuff` to a package and have it picked up by `setuptools`. But how could I possibly add `INFO.txt` to my `.egg`?

## Edit

The proposed solutions using something along the lines of

```
package_data = { '' : ['moredata.txt','INFO.txt']}
```

does not work for me because the files `moredata` and `INFO.txt` do not belong to a package, but are part of a separate folder that is only part of the module as a whole, not of any individual package. 
As explained above, this could be fixed in the case of `moredata.txt` by adding a `__init__.py` file to `additionpythonalstuff`, thus promoting it to a package. However, this is not an elegant solution and does not work at all for `INFO.txt`, which lives in the top-level directory.

## Solution

Based on the accepted answer, here's the solution

This is the `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='mytest',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='A sample Python project',
    author='Test',
    zip_safe=False,
    author_email='test@test.com',
    keywords='test',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={'': ['INFO.txt', 'moredata.txt'],
                  'somepackage':['data.txt']},
    data_files=[('.',['INFO.txt']),
                ('additionalstuff',['additionalstuff/moredata.txt'])],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

And this is the `MANIFEST.in`:

```
include INFO.txt
graft additionalstuff
include somepackage/*.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including non-Python files with setup.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. In the given question, the accepted solution is to use `package_data`. This I have already done. Please take note that the given solution to use `''` (empty string) does not work for me since it explicitly refers to "all packages", which does not apply to me, since the file I want to add does not belong to *any* package, which is precisely the problem I'm facing.

Comment: How is INFO.txt referenced from inside somepackage.  I tried this but now the relative paths between somepackage and INFO.txt has changed.

Comment: See [data-files-support in setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html#data-files-support).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is also `data_files`

```
data_files=[("yourdir",
             ["additionalstuff/moredata.txt", "INFO.txt"])],
```

Have a think about where you want to put those files. More info in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files).

Comment: Will `yourdir` be relative to the dir where package gets installed?

Comment: Yes. From docs: *If directory is a relative path, it is interpreted relative to the installation prefix*.

Comment: That was my understanding too. but it is just taking the root prefix and is not installing in the intended package I want it to. Maybe I am doing something wrong. If you know how to do this would you mind posting an example or answering this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653195/add-folders-and-subfolders-outside-of-main-module-using-setuptoolssetup-py/59662834#59662834

Comment: @mad_ I have experienced the same. On some platforms it will place it correctly, on some it won't. It is better to use package_data and move files to the package beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `package_data`. Put your `setup.py` in the root directory, then you just need to:

```
package_data={'': [
    'somepackage/*.txt',
    'additionalstuff/*.txt',
    '*.txt',
]
```

Comment: This response relies on the feature of `''` to refer to "all packages". However, the file `INFO.txt` does not belong to *any* package and is thus not picked up.

Comment: It does work for me. I have the exact same directory tree configuration as you do and in the root of my project I just have a README.md and setup.py. The README.md is correctly included using package_data.

Comment: This surprises me. I have created a small testcase and again observe the same problem. You seem to do something differently from what I am doing. Could you provide a link to the mentioned project so I can investigate the architecture?

Comment: Sadly no, because it's in a private repository on github. However pacholik answer should be more correct than mine.

Comment: This does not work for me. `data_files` fixes it but it's deprecated. What is the standard solution? Here is my file https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/blob/master/setup.py