# Unable to push text files to pypi

Tags: python, circleci, pypi, twine

I'm having some problems trying to push my package to pypi.
Everything is fine and smooth but `twine` doesn't upload text files.

You can find repo here: https://github.com/piotr-rarus/evobench

Pipeline is here: https://github.com/piotr-rarus/evobench/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml

Code uploads successfully, but I can' access text files located at `evobench/discrete/isg/data`.
I would like to ship those files with a package.

Thanks for help <3

**Update 1**

I've tried to include `package_data`:

```py
package_data={
    'evobench': ['*.txt', 'evobench/discrete/isg/data/*.txt']
},
include_package_data=True,
```

Doesn't work :/

**Update 2**

This works:

```py
package_data={
    'evobench.discrete.isg': ['data/*.txt']
},
include_package_data=True,
```

Comment: I think you need to add `data_files` like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609248/setuptools-adding-additional-files-outside-package)

Comment: Don't use `data_files`. `package_data`, or `include_package_data` in combination with a correct `MANIFEST.in` are the correct solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494/11138259