# Including data files with setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, setup.py

I'm having trouble including data files in my setup.py script. My package is setup as follows:

```
my_package/
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in

    my_package/
        __init__.py
        access_data.py

        data_files/
            my_data_file.csv
```

I want to include the `my_data_file.csv` file when installing so that it can be read by `access_data.py`. To do so I used the `package_data` keyword in `setuptools`:

```
setup(...,
      packages=['my_package'],
      package_data={'my_package': ['./my_package/data_files/my_data_file.csv']},
      include_package_data=True
      )
```

I also included the file in `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include my_package/data_files *
```

`setup.py` seems to run fine and doesn't throw any errors. However, when I import the package I get a file not found error because `my_data_file.csv` is missing. I have tried referencing other stack overflow questions (particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)) but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can I get setup.py to include the necessary data files?

Comment: Are you on a case-insensitive filesystem? `manifest.in` really should be `MANIFEST.in`. But that doesn't matter anyway as `MANIFEST.in` is used for source distribution (sdist).

Comment: First think in debugging is to split The Big Problem into many smaller ones. Let's do it step by step. Step number 1: check that you distribution (sdist, egg or wheel) really contains `my_data_file.csv`; if not — fix `setup.py` to include it. Step number 2: check that `my_data_file.csv` is installed. Step 3 — debug why you cannot access the file even if it's in place (wrong path to the file? permissions?)

Comment: your line should be `package_data={'my_package': ['data_files/my_data_file.csv']},` (under the `my_package` package, there's no `my_package` directory)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If it is listed in `setup.py`'s `package_data` (correctly) you shouldn't need to include it in `MANIFEST.in` (as it will be included automatically)

In your case, the error is with your `package_data` line, the paths are relative to the namespace's root

In your case it should be:

```
package_data={'my_package': ['data_files/my_data_file.csv']},
```

Also note that the key in package data is the dotted module path (it's not super relevant for this toy case however).

Comment: For those who did not know at once what the dotted name exactly is: `Packages are a way of structuring Python’s module namespace by using “dotted module names”. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A.` ([source link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html))

Comment: How do you include all in a folder?

Comment: @JohnAndrews it supports globs, so use a `*` -- [for example](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/blob/0fd4a2ea38df4f276e43397e21ecb3fcbc96d122/setup.cfg#L48)