# create setup.py with data files included

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I have a python3 code with the following tree.

```
ptbl/
├── dialogue.py
├── elem_H.py
├── elems.db
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.py.in
├── __main__.py
├── main.py
├── menu.py
├── __pycache__
├── retrive.py
└── veggards.py
data/
├── icons
├── Makefile
├── Makefile.am
├── Makefile.in
├── menubar.ui
├── org.example.ptbl.gschema.valid
├── org.example.ptbl.gschema.xml
├── ptbl.desktop
├── ptbl.desktop.in
└── ui
bin/
├── ptbl
└── ptbl.in
```

I have never used setup.py, and from the `tree`, you can see that I was working with `autotools`.

I have generate a basic `setup.py`, but it is not including anything from data, bin or the ptbl/elems.db:

my `steup.py` is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
  name="ptbl",
  version="0.4",
  packages=find_packages(),
  package_data={
    'ptbl': ["data/"],
  },
)
```

which is making the dist:

```
.
├── PKG-INFO
├── ptbl
│   ├── dialogue.py
│   ├── elem_H.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── menu.py
│   ├── retrive.py
│   └── veggards.py
├── ptbl.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── setup.cfg
└── setup.py
```

What should I do to include other files? 
I have checked other similar questions here, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147837/including-data-files-with-setup-py)
but can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

List files or patterns:

```
package_data={
    'ptbl': ["bin/*", "data/*"],
},
```