# Adding non-python files to setup.py

Tags: python

I am trying to add `*.ui` & `*.png` files to `setup.py` and this is what I have so far

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

from smlgui import __version__

setup(
    name='smlgui',
    version=__version__,
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://github.com/akshaybabloo/SML-GUI',
    license='MIT',
    author='Akshay Raj Gollahalli',
    author_email='akshay@gollahalli.com',
    description='Data exporter for Spikes Markup Language (SML).',
    requires=['click', 'pyqt'],
    scripts=['sml.sh', 'sml.cmd'],
    package_data={'smlgui': ['*.ui', '*.png']},
    include_package_data=True
)
```

I am not sure what is happening but when I try to do `python setup.py install` or `pip install .` only `*.py` gets installed.

I tried to follow the procedure given here -> [Including non-Python files with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py) but it just did not help.

Also, I created `MANIFEST.in` that has

```
include *.ui
include *.png
```

I am not sure if I have to tell `setup.py` to read this file or it is automatically done.

My file structure is

```
root_folder
|
|   MANIFEST.in
|   setup.py
|   sml.cmd
|   sml.sh
|
+---smlgui
|   |   main.py
|   |   processor.py
|   |   utility.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   +---gui
|   |   |   about.ui
|   |   |   main.ui
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |
|   |   \---assets
|   |           logo.png
|   |           spikes-logo.png
|   |           __init__.py
|   |
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it. Make sure you have the complete path in the `MANIFEST.in` file. Something like:

```
include smlgui/gui/*.ui
include smlgui/gui/assets/*.png
```

Then test it by creating a wheel, by doing

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Under `build` folder you should be able to see all the contents.

Comment: But in this case inside build our python (.py) files present, if user changes it's effects on hole package

Comment: You saved my day as well!