# Including non-python files in a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, manifest

I created and published a Python package, but I just can't get it to include a text file.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/void4/gimpscm

The file I need to include is procdump.txt, located in the gimpscm-directory.

So the layout is like this:

```
setup.py
setup.cfg
MANIFEST.in
gimpscm/
       /__index__.py
       /procdump.txt
       /(other .py files)
```

I tried:

- including a package_data directive in setup.py
- various MANIFEST.in directives

The current setup.py includes:

```
  package_data = {"gimpscm": ["gimpscm/procdump.txt"]},
  include_package_data=True,
```

And MANIFEST.in contains:

```
recursive-include gimpscm *.txt
```

The txt file is included like the .py files in the gimpscm subdirectory of the zip in the dist directory. But when I `pip install gimpscm`, the file simply isn't installed.

I publish the package this way:

```sh
python setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/*
```

On the pypi website, the uploaded package DOES include the txt file, it just isn't included on the `pip install`.

This process so far has been extremely frustrating, and Stackoverflow and other sites do not give a clear answer. I've tried both the MANIFEST.in and setup.py directive approaches, in every combination. It still doesn't work. The Python docs are also too convoluted and unclear for me.

Comment: Add it under `package_data`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including non-Python files with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)

Comment: @vin I did, see the edited question

Comment: @vin I tried both approaches, in every combination, it still doesn't work. I've checked all related stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Does simply using `include_package_data=True` work ? 
PS: this usually works for me

Comment: @vin I have. Or do you mean just this statement, and omitting package_data?

Comment: yes omit package data and just use the `include_package_data` option

Comment: Also try`from setuptools import setup, find_packages` instead of  `from distutils.core import setup`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is a combination of @m.rp and @vin's answers:

Instead of `from distutils.core import setup`
use

```
from setuptools import setup
```

include the following argument to the setup() call

```
include_package_data=True,
```

and ONLY use the MANIFEST.in to include files, where the directory is specified relative from the location where the MANIFEST.in file is.

```
recursive-include gimpscm *.txt
```

What a massive PITA this was. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

`include_package_data` is part of the `setuptools` distro and not `distutils`
Try something like follows

```
  from setuptools import setup, find_packages

  setup(name="",
        version="0.1.0",
        packages=find_packages(),
        include_package_data=True,
        setup_requires=["pytest-runner"],
        tests_require=["pytest",
                       "mock"],
        test_suite="pytest",
        install_requires=[],
        entry_points={"console_scripts": []})
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using both MANIFEST.in and package_data, many sources discourage this use, since you give two sources of truth that can easily be inconsistent with each other.

Use just MANIFEST.in and include_package_data = True

Additional Sources:
https://blog.ionelmc.ro/presentations/packaging/#slide:15

Comment: This does not work for me, see https://pypi.org/project/gimpscm/1.1/
The .txt is still included in the uploaded package, but does not appear in the pip installed package.