# How to add type stub file (.pyi) to module only project?

Tags: python, mypy

I want to add a type stub file (.pyi) to my module-only project. The projects consists as follows:

```
foo.py
foo.pyi
setup.py
```

I know `foo.py` should be added to `py_modules` arguments in `setup` function.
But I don't know where `foo.pyi` should be added.

The repository I'm trying to handle is https://github.com/studio-ousia/mojimoji

Comment: looks like [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py) can help

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Thanks! I tried all the methods described in the link you suggested, but it didn't work..