# Github Action not using manifest file when building Python package

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I'm trying to publish a Python package using Github Actions, but it's not reading from `manifest.in` during the build stage so it's skipping out on some files.

This is my file structure:

```
src
│   test.py
│
└───bashbox
    │   bashbox.py
    │   __init__.py
    │   __main__.py
    │
    └───themes
            barebone.bsh
            double.bsh
            example._bsh
            single.bsh
```

And this is my publishing action:

```yaml
# This workflow will upload a Python Package using Twine when a release is created
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/en/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-python-with-github-actions#publishing-to-package-registries

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

name: Upload Python Package

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install build
        pip install wheel
    - name: Build package
      run: python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
    - name: Publish package
      uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@27b31702a0e7fc50959f5ad993c78deac1bdfc29
      with:
        user: __token__
        password: ${{ secrets.PYPI_API_TOKEN }}
```

My manifest file is meant to add the `themes` folder to the package when its built, but the action skips over the manifest as if not there. How do I fix this?

If it helps, the repository for the package is [here](https://github.com/bash-elliott/bashbox).

Comment: I believe this could answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py

Comment: @Peterrabbit I'm trying to build this using github actions but the action is just completely skipping over the files. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe you could update you question and tags to say that this a problem related to github actions. It's not very understandable right now.