# How to add package data to pyproject.toml when using hatchling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**NOTE** This question relates to `hatch` (not `setuptools` nor `distutils`).

I am developing my first package and I am following [this](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) guide.

My project structure is as follows:

```
mypackage
│   LICENSE
│   pyproject.toml
│   README.md
│   requiremets.txt            
├───docs
├───scripts          
├───src
│   └───mypackage
│          config.py
│          first_module.py
│          datatypes.py
│          utils.py
│          first_module.py
│          __init__.py         
└───tests
```

However, I noticed that in `C:\Users\<User>\Miniconda3\envs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\mypackage` there is only the content of `./mypackage/scr/mypackage` of the above tree.

What I want to achieve is to install also the scripts folder, because in the source code I am defining a function

```
def open_tutorial() -> None:
    site_packages = next(
        p for p in sys.path if "site-packages" in p
    )
    open(site_packages+"\\mypackage\\scripts\\tutorial.py")
```

that would allow the user to run a code like the following

```
import mypackage as mpkg

mpkg.open_tutorial()
```

What I expect is that the `scripts/tutorial.py` opens in the user editor.

How to achieve my goal? I guess that I should edit something in the `pyproject.toml` file, or that I have to set `hatch` in some way but I have no idea how. Any suggestion?

Related question: I would like that to work for any OS, so any hints on how shall I change my `open_tutorial()` function is welcome! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including non-Python files with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py)

Comment: Hum, not really. The problem is that I am using hatchling (not setuptools nor distutils) I have updated the question.

Comment: I found a solution: I have to add this `[tool.hatch.build.force-include]
"scripts" = "mypackage/scripts"` but the problem is that it also install the `__pycache__` folders. :(

Comment: If that works,you can add it as answer; it'll help future readers

Answer (score 7):

The solution:

```
[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
only-include = ["src/mypackage", "scripts"]

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel.sources]
"src" = ""
"scripts" = "mypackage/scripts"
```

from [here](https://github.com/pypa/hatch/issues/492).